# rename Spree::Image after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Image files should be renamed as `[variant-name]-[underscored-option-type].jpg` for variants. I have come this far.

**Updated Code**

```
Spree::Image.class_eval do

 after_save :change_file_name

 private

  def change_file_name
    if self.viewable.kind_of? Spree::Variant
      product_name = self.viewable.product.name.downcase.gsub(" ","_")
      underscored_option_types = get_underscored_option_types
      random_number = rand(10000...1000000)
      extension = File.extname(self.attachment_file_name).downcase
      attachment_file_name = product_name+"-"+underscored_option_types+"-"+"#{random_number}"+"#{extension}"
      self.update_column(:attachment_file_name, attachment_file_name)
    end
  end

end
```

This code renames `attachment_file_name` column only. How to change image's name? Even `self.save` won't work, considering I escape recursive loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to rename the files at their respective locations, as there are different styles (version) of images stored. You have to rename each versions of an image at their respective locations. I hope the following code will help someone.cheers :)

```
Spree::Image.class_eval do

 after_save :change_file_name

 private

  def change_file_name
    @skip_change_file_name ||= false
    return if @skip_change_file_name
    if self.viewable.kind_of? Spree::Variant
      product_name = self.viewable.product.name.downcase.gsub(" ","_")
      underscored_option_types = get_underscored_option_types
      random_number = rand(10000...1000000)
      extension = File.extname(self.attachment_file_name).downcase
      new_file_name = product_name+"-"+underscored_option_types+"-"+"#{random_number}"+"#{extension}"
      (self.attachment.styles.keys+[:original]).each do |style|
        FileUtils.move(self.attachment.path(style), File.join(File.dirname(self.attachment.path(style)), new_file_name))
      end
    self.attachment_file_name = new_file_name
    @skip_change_file_name = true
    self.save!
    end
  end

end
```